# Using egg whites as DNA destruction test possible?

Tags: dna, biochemistry, forensics

My current theory to test for the destruction of any DNA that may be used as forensic evidence is to use an egg white. I would like to test various myths and methods for destroying DNA evidence and need a sure-fire method of testing whether or not the DNA is destroyed. The reasoning behind the egg white is because when you cook one or expose it to strong acids or bases, it turns white. Indicating the denaturing of the proteins within the whites. Would this work to test for the denaturing of DNA molecules to? Several experiments would be conducted with each method, using egg whites to determine whether or not the DNA would be destroyed. Would egg whites, with great accuracy, determine whether or not the sample can be identified. If not, could you please suggest another alternative?

Comment: just a side note: do you want to destroy DNA (e.g. remove traces of DNA presence) or damage it so that investigator won't be able to assign given DNA to particular person?

Comment: @aaaaaa First I'd try damaging DNA and then move on to removing any trace of it.

Comment: what is the end goal of this project? BTW this community does not support illegal activities

Comment: @aaaaaa Mabye create a youtube series and destroy the myltiple biohazardous samples ive collected from myself over the past month.

Comment: This isn't a valid test as egg white contains a lot of proteins and DNA is chemically completely different. For example you can heat DNA several times to 95°C and you will not damage it (in fact it renaturates when cooled down slow enough), but this is not possible with proteins. "Biohazard samples" (whatever this means in your case) are deactivated either by autoclaving or by incubating the cells/tubes/whatever with chlorine bleach. Both methods work well and are approved in labs.

Comment: Egg white would not destroy DNA. Egg white is composed primarily of proteins. How does denaturation of proteins upon heating in any way link with the proteins being able to destroy DNA? Since your hypothesis is not correct, the question is unclear.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I am not stating that the egg whites will be used to destroy DNA, instead I'm asking whether egg whites can be subjected to the same treatment and indicate if such treatment would have destroyed DNA. That is if I had enough DNA material and replaced the egg whites with DNA. I am trying to find a cheap solution to test whether or not the DNA would have been destroyed because I do not have the equipment to do so. Mabye try a bit more to comprehend the question next time.

Comment: @Chris Thank you. This should have been used as an answer, exactly what I was looking for. And the samples are mainly blood. Though I dont have an autoclave, I will use a NaOH and NaClO solution.

Comment: @TommyWoldt This was more a quick comment - but I can make it an answer later if you like.

Comment: @Chris I dont think that the question is going to be "unholded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cooking DNA will absolutely not destroy it. Few things will actually destroy DNA. Bleach is one of the only common substances that will do it.

To test for DNA quantity you need to perform qPCR. The equipment is $20,000+.